# User Cant See Name of Users Entered Before Him (websocket PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

Basically I am making a websocket chatting application in PHP and i have made a div that shows all online users.But the problem with my code is when a new user enters the room , he just can see the names of the users entering the room after him and cant see the name of users entered be4 him.

For instance , if **Batman,Joker and Robin** entered the room respectively then Joker can see robin's name but cant see Batman's Name in the userList.
Here is my code:
**Client Side:**

```
 <div style="height:760px; width:200px; margin-left:450px;border-style:solid;"id='userlist'> 
  </div>
```

This is the DIV element where i want my userlist.
   
**JS code:**

```
 var msg = {
    name: myname,
    color : '<?php echo $colours[$user_colour]; ?>'
    };
 websocket.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

Then server recieve this data and Heres the part of the **server** side code:

```
 $tst_msg = json_decode($received_text); //json decode 
 $user_name = $tst_msg->name; //sender name
 $response_text = mask(json_encode(array('name'=>$user_name)));
 send_message($response_text); //function to send data to the client side
```

Now heres the **client** side code for recieving the data:

```
websocket.onmessage = function(ev) {
  var msg = JSON.parse(ev.data); 
  var uname = msg.name; //user name
//code to check if same name doesnt appear twice
     if(!$('#userlist:has(li.'+uname+')').length>0){
     $('#userlist').append('<li class="'+uname+'" >'+uname+'</li>');
 } 
    };
```

What can be a workaround to solve this problem? Any ideas? Hope I made sense.

Comment: where are you storing the list of current users in the room?

Comment: I m not storing it anywhere...... whenever a user connects to the server, I m appending the "userlist" DIV element with the name of the user..... and when the connection closes i m deleting the name of the user.

Comment: Take the first comment as a hint on how to resolve your issue.

Comment: Then that is your problem - scripts cant store temporary information - so when a new user enters the room it is appended to a div - but existing users the code to append has already fired - you must store them in a database and when a new user joins the room query the current list of users and return it

Comment: Ah , so i should store the name when user connects in some text file or a database ,right?

Comment: exactly! - scripts are 'dumb' they dont remember anything once they have run unless you store it somewhere (file, db etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code this is what is happening

Batman enters room - script fires to append current users to list - noone is there so nothing is appended.

Joker enters room - script is fired and it is appended to batman - but the script has fired to add batman already so Joker doesn't know batman is there.

A script will not store temporary information

i.e. if you EXPLICITLY declare users = batman, robin, joker - the script knows this.

BUT if you fire a script and store them in a array or similar in that script the second the script has finished running it forgets what you have stored.

Hope that helps - just remember 'SCRIPTS CANNOT REMEMBER ANYTHING I TELL THEM WITHOUT HELP' - it will make it more obvious that you need a storage mecahnism for temporary stuff.

Hope that helps and good luck!

Comment: No Problem! Have fun - one of first things I wrote was chat room - it is complex!!!!